# python script is not working in powershell

Tags: python, powershell

I am a newbie in python. Trying to learn by my own. 
Below is my python program. When I tried to run it in the Powershell. It just stuck. 
It will never show any output. I don't see any errors on the screen.

```
from sys import argv

script, name = argv

print "this is: ", script
print "my name is: ", name
age = raw_input("what is your age: ")
height = raw_input("what is your height")

print "so your name is %s, your age is %s and height is %r" %(name, age, height)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you do not get any errors in powershell, but there are quite a few issues with the code as it is, most of them, most likely, due to faulty copy paste, but the one causing the hang your lies in the line:

```
script, name = argv
```

To explain it, lets refer [to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv):

> sys.argv The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script.
>   argv[0] is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether
>   this is a full pathname or not). If the command was executed using the
>   -c command line option to the interpreter, argv[0] is set to the string '-c'. If no script name was passed to the Python interpreter,
>   argv[0] is the empty string.

So what you are looking for is something like this (with fixed lines):

```
from sys import argv

script, name = argv[0], argv[1]

print "this is: ", script 
print "my name is: ", name 
age = raw_input("what is your age: ") 
height = raw_input("what is your height")

print "so your name is %s, your age is %s and height is %r" %(name, age, height)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work:

```
from sys import argv

script, name = argv

print ("this is: ", script)
print ("my name is: ", name)
age = input("what is your age: ")
height = input("what is your height")

print ("so your name is {}, your age is {} and height is {}" .format(name, age, height))
```

---

There are couple of updates in Python 3, so I am guessing that is why there must be some syntax error.

I am also a beginner (this is my first answer here at stackoverflow) and I have been following the book Learn Python the hard way. I faced the same problem like yours:

1. The raw_input does not work with Python 3
2. Printing needs () mandatory.
3. %r somehow does not work running through shell and I would like to know answer to this.